# Best way to handle a Maven transitive dep version?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm not quite sure of the best way to handle the following situation in my Maven project...

I have two direct dependencies A and B. Both depend on different versions of C. Dependency A is compatible with both versions of C, but dependency B is only compatible with it's declared version of C. I'd like to simply use whatever version of C that B declares.

I realize that I can exclude the dependency of C in dependency A, but then if I ever removed dependency B or if C was removed as a dependency of B...A would not work anymore.

I also realize that I can declare B's current version of C in my dependency management section, but then I would not seamlessly get the change if B ever changed it's version of C.

**What is the prescribed way to handle this sort of situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way as recommended, although, slightly indirectly, by the maven docs is to use the `dependency management` feature. Quoting the [doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management),

> A second, and very important use of the dependency management section
>   is to control the versions of artifacts used in transitive
>   dependencies.

I can understand that you are forced to update the version of `C` on your target project, say `T`, every time `B` uses a new version of `C`, but you also have to look at this from the `T's` POV - the target project `T`, ought to know and be able to control all the versions of the transitive dependencies it has.